# Multiplying the value of two django integer fields

Tags: python, django, user-interface

I am having trouble multiplying the values of two IntegerFields in Django. I am new to Django so I am probably missing something obvious. 
Here is the error I am getting:

```
       NameError at /multiplication/multiplied
       name 'multiply_two_integers' is not defined
       Request Method:  POST
       Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/multiplication/multiplied
       Django Version:  2.0.1
       Exception Type:  NameError
       Exception Value: 
       name 'multiply_two_integers' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
    from django import forms

    class HomeForm(forms.Form):
      quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)
      quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)
      def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
        return x*y
      def return_product(self):
        return multiply_two_integers(quantity1,quantity2)
```

And:

```
      from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
      from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
      from django.template import RequestContext
      from django.views.generic import TemplateView
      from multiplication.forms import HomeForm
      # Create your views here.
      # def startPage(request):
      #     return render(request, 'multiplication/detail.html')

     template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'
     template_name2 = 'multiplication/multiplied.html'

     def get(request):
       form = HomeForm()
       return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form} )

     def post(request):
       form = HomeForm(request.POST)
       if (form.is_valid()):
           product = form.return_product()
           return render(request, template_name2, {'form': form, 
          'product': product })
```

And template_name1:

```
     <h1>Multiplication Function</h1>
     <form action =  "{% url 'multiplication:post' %}" method = "post">
     {{ form.as_p  }}
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type = "submit" value ="Multiply">
     <!--<button type="submit"> Multiply </button>-->
     <h1>{{product}}</h1>
     </form>
```

template_name2:

```
     <h1>{{product}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not like a Django error, this is a Basic Python OOP error!!.
In Python class method(non-static), you have to invoke the first argument as **self**. So in forms.py.

```
from django import forms

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
  quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)
  quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)

  def multiply_two_integers(self, x, y):
    return x*y

  def return_product(self):
    return self.multiply_two_integers(self.quantity1, self.quantity2)
```

or you can also make the **multiply_two_integers** as a staticmethod by simply decorating this method

```
from django import forms

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
  quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)
  quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required = False)

  @staticmethod
  def multiply_two_integers(x, y):
    return x*y

  def return_product(self):
    return self.multiply_two_integers(self.quantity1, self.quantity2)
```

And additionally, I want to suggest that, do not make these methods(multiply_two_integers and return_product) in **forms**, rather make these forms in **views** instead. Just fetch the form value by `request.POST['field']`

Comment: still getting an error: AttributeError at /multiplication/multiplied
'HomeForm' object has no attribute 'quantity1'

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer at last,  please create these methods in views.py instead of forms.py. During posting the form, you can have the values which have been filled in form.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did that but I still got an error: "ValueError at /multiplication/multiplied
The view multiplication.views.post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: wait no sorry I meant I am getting this error: TypeError at /multiplication/multiplied
'QueryDict' object is not callable
Request Method: POST

Comment: Can you share your class/function views in which you are getting error? Can you share your views code

Comment: sure. This is what I have ;

Comment: class myForm(forms.Form):
    quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

form = myForm()

def get(request):
    return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form} )

def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
    return x*y

def post(request):
    if (form.is_valid()):
       x = request.POST('quantity1')
       y = request.POST('quantity2')
       product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
       return render(request, template_name2, {'form': form, 'product': product })

Comment: and: from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django import forms
from multiplication.forms import HomeForm
# Create your views here.

# def startPage(request):
#     return render(request, 'multiplication/detail.html')

template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'
template_name2 = 'multiplication/multiplied.html'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `self`:

```
def return_product(self):
    return self.multiply_two_integers(quantity1, quantity2)
```